# defineEmit in composition API and typecast it properly in my composable

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I define an emit in my `<script setup lang="ts">` and I want to send that emit to my composable to actually do the emitting for me.

However, I do need to cast my received parameter to something (because `any` is obviously not very nice and unknown doesn't think `emit` is a function)

I have the below code:

```
export type EmitType = {
    'search': [value: string]
}
```

And I initialize the composable with something like this:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const emit = defineEmits<EmitType>();

useComposable(emit);
</script>
```

I then use `EmitType` to cast my `emit` parameter

```
const useMyComposable(emit: EmitType) {
  emit('search', 'a string');
}
```

By doing the above my `emit()` in the composable gives the error:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Type 'EmitType' has no call signatures.
```

Which I understand because `defineEmits` most likely has a different type.

So in short my question is:
How can I properly define `emit` in my composable to be error-free, not use `any` as a type and have the proper intellisense?

Comment: You typed EmitType  to be an object, but emit a function

Comment: Well, Yes. But that's because I send the `defineEmits` result to my composable, That's the one I need; I just don't know how to typecast that one

Comment: t's supposed to be EmitFn<EmitType>, can't verify if is exported but I'd expect that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick. As your typescript error said, your previous type was not callable. This is.

```
type EmitType = {
    (event: "search", value: string): void;
};

const emit = defineEmits<EmitType>();

const runEmit = (emit: EmitType) => {
    emit("search", "string");
};
```

edit:
See https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-emits

Comment: This did the trick, such a simple fix and a dumb one on my part. Thanks for setting this straight